# Popstate event not triggered after pushing twice to history using history.pushState()

Tags: javascript, browser-history, event-listener, pushstate, popstate

I’m working on an eshop where items are opened on top of a page in iframes. I’m using

`history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", http://localhost:8888/product-category/tyger/vara-tyger/?view=product&item=test-4);`

in order to let customers copy the current url and use it to go to the current page with the item opened in an iframe. In addition, I’m using

`window.addEventListener('popstate', manageHistory);`

```
function manageHistory(event) {
    if (!has_gone_back) {
        var iframeOpen = false;
        has_gone_back = true;
    }
    else {
        var iframeOpen = true;
        has_gone_back = false;
    }
}
```

in order to let customers use their browser’s back and forward buttons for navigation (closing and opening the iframe).

However, when opening one product (calling `history.pushState` once), using the browser’s back button, and opening another product (calling `history.pushState` again), and going back again, `manageHistory()` is not called. The customer is taken to the first opened product but if pressing back again, `manageHistory()` is called.

I want `manageHistory()` to be called when pressing back on the product page opened second in order to add code to redirect customers to the category's start page when pressing back.

I’ve tried both adding Event Listeners for both opened products and also for only the first one. Any ideas what the problem may be?

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate

> Note that just calling history.pushState() or history.replaceState() won't trigger a popstate event. The popstate event is only triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back button (or calling history.back() in JavaScript).

You can overwrite `popState` and `replaceState`, but what is generally a better idea is to create a wrapper which sets the url and then triggers your handler function.

Something like this...

```
function urlChangeHandler() {
  var url = window.location.href;

  // Whatever you want to do...
}

// Handle initial url:
urlChangeHandler();

window.addEventListener('popstate', urlChangeHandler);

var urlState = {
  push: function(url) {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, url);
    urlChangeHandler();
  },
  replace: function(url) {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);
    urlChangeHandler();
  }
}
```

I have a similar file in one of my projects which updates the datastore based on the #hash...

```
import tree from './state'


// No need for react-router for such a simple application.

function hashChangeHandler(commit) {
  return () => {
    const hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);

    const cursor = tree.select('activeContactIndex');
    const createCursor = tree.select('createNewContact');

    cursor.set(null);
    createCursor.set(false);

    (() => {
      if(!hash.length) {
        // Clean up the url (remove the hash if there is nothing after it):
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
        return;
      }

      if(hash === 'new') {
        createCursor.set(true);
        return;
      }

      const index = parseInt(hash, 10);
      if(!isNaN(index)) {
        cursor.set(index);
      }
    })();
    commit && tree.commit();
  }
}

// Handle initial url:
hashChangeHandler(true)();

// Handle manual changes of the hash in the url:
window.addEventListener('hashchange', hashChangeHandler(true));

function createHash(location) {
  return (location !== null) ? `#${location}` : window.location.pathname;
}

module.exports = {
  push: (location, commit=true) => {
    window.history.pushState(null, null, createHash(location));
    hashChangeHandler(commit)();
  },
  replace: (location, commit=true) => {
    window.history.replaceState(null, null, createHash(location));
    hashChangeHandler(commit)();
  }
}
```

Comment: When I try to use your code I get `Unexpected token '>'`. I'm using Wordpress, do I need to add a library or something?

Comment: This is just example code that I whipped up. It's an edited version of the second code snippet, which I copied from one of my projects. It's actually a module and expects you to use something like `webpack` or `browserify`. Also, there is ES2015 syntax, so you'd need a transpiler such as babel. Read it, understand what it does, and reimplement it in your application. I'll rewrite it to vanilla javascript.